# Showing inline images in the Notebook with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I copied the code from the sample of the documentation of [`patches.BoxStyle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.BoxStyle) and I added three things in order to use it in the [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html):

- `%matplotlib inline` to plot inline in the Notebook
- `plt.title()` otherwise the plot wouldn't show up
- `print()` to see what prints a few `194 (194, 2)`

When I execute the code in the Notebook I do see the image in the browser, but I don't understand a few things:

- Why doesn't the image show without the `plt.title()`?
- Why does it show 3 lines with `194 (194, 2)`?
- What is the `plt.draw()` for? (If I remove it the result does not change)

Here is my modified code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.patches as mpatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

styles = mpatch.BoxStyle.get_styles()

figheight = (len(styles)+.5)
fig1 = plt.figure(1, (4/1.5, figheight/1.5))
fontsize = 0.3 * 72

for i, (stylename, styleclass) in enumerate(styles.items()):
    fig1.text(0.5, (float(len(styles)) - 0.5 - i)/figheight, stylename,
              ha="center",
              size=fontsize,
              transform=fig1.transFigure,
              bbox=dict(boxstyle=stylename, fc="w", ec="k"))

plt.title('Here is the title')
print('a')
plt.draw()
print('b')
plt.show()
```